# VBA find second instance of the same value (column name)

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 workbooks with same column names. workbook 1 is empty and in workbook 1 i paste values from workbook 2.

I have a list of columns I need (some columns are repeating as there is different data in the same named columns), so the steps of the code are the following

1. take first column name from the list
2. go to wkb2 find column name and copy all the data from that column
3. go to wkb1 find column name, paste all the data in that column

the issue is, I have some column names which are repeating e.g.:

```
wkb1 - column names                         wkb2 - column names
x  x  x  x  A  B  C  x  x  x  A  B  C       x  x  x  x  A  B  C  x  x  x  A  B  C
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .   
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
.  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .       .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
```

once I get to the columns which are repeating, the macro doesnt move forwart (to the right, next column) but it takes the first column it finds with the same name, e.g. first column A instead of second column A.

I cant figure out a descent solution for this.

thank you.

Code below
PS I pasted a working solution with the current issue, as I have alot of failed iterations of the code with failed ideas how to deal with the stated issue.

```
Public DailyFolder As String
Public DailyHSBC As String

Public wkb_macro As Excel.Workbook
Public wks_macro As Excel.Worksheet

Public wkb_HSBC_concat As Excel.Workbook
Public wks_HSBC_concat As Excel.Worksheet

Public wkb_HSBC_raw As Excel.Workbook
Public wks_HSBC_raw As Excel.Worksheet

Sub ConcatFiles()

    Dim HSBC_temp As Excel.Workbook

    HSBC_columns = wks_macro.Range(Range("H2"), Range("H2").End(xlDown))
    HSBC_FileList = wks_macro.Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown))

    Fund_Accounting_Positions = wks_macro.Range("D5")

    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs (DailyHSBC & "\concatenate_HSBC.csv")

    Set wkb_HSBC_concat = Excel.Workbooks("concatenate_HSBC.csv")
    Set wks_HSBC_concat = Excel.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    x = 1

    For Each col In HSBC_columns

        wks_HSBC_concat.Cells(1, x).Value = col
        x = x + 1

    Next

    y = 1
    msg = "Files not processed:"

    For Each Item In HSBC_FileList

        ofs_rows = wks_HSBC_concat.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Set HSBC_temp = Workbooks.Open(DailyHSBC & Item & "*.*")

        On Error Resume Next
        For Each col In HSBC_columns

            HSBC_temp.Sheets(Fund_Accounting_Positions).Range(HSBC_temp.Sheets(Fund_Accounting_Positions).Cells.Find(What:=col, MatchCase:=True).Offset(1, 0).Address, HSBC_temp.Sheets(Fund_Accounting_Positions).Cells.Find(What:=col, MatchCase:=True).End(xlDown).Address).Copy

            If err.Number <> 0 Then

                msg = msg & vbCrLf & Item
                GoTo Line1

            Else
                wks_HSBC_concat.Cells.Find(What:=col, MatchCase:=True).Offset(ofs_rows, 0).PasteSpecial  

                End If

            End If

        Next

Line1:

        HSBC_temp.Close
    Next

MsgBox msg

End Sub
```

Comment: The new `XMATCH` function could be useful for locating the 2nd instance of a column name, but that's currently only on Office 365 Insider builds. You could use `Range.Find` to locate the first column, and `Range.FindNext` to locate the second; if `FindNext` yields `Nothing`, there's no 2nd instance. That said, column names in tables should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an interesting situation. See if below column mapping logic helps your case.

```
Public Sub ColumnLogic()
Dim wkbDest As Workbook: Set wkbDest = Workbooks("Book2 (version 1).xlsb")
Dim wkbSrce As Workbook: Set wkbSrce = Workbooks("Book1 (version 1).xlsb")
Dim wksDest As Worksheet: Set wksDest = wkbDest.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim wksSrce As Worksheet: Set wksSrce = wkbSrce.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim objDict As Object
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim lngArr()
ReDim lngArr(wksDest.Cells(1, wksDest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1)

'Map columns
Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = 1 To wksDest.Cells(1, wksDest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If objDict.exists(wksDest.Cells(1, i).Value) Then
        k = objDict(wksDest.Cells(1, i).Value) + 1
    Else
        k = 1
    End If
    For j = k To wksSrce.Cells(1, wksSrce.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If wksDest.Cells(1, i).Value = wksSrce.Cells(1, j).Value Then
            lngArr(i - 1) = j
            If objDict.exists(wksDest.Cells(1, i).Value) Then
                objDict(wksDest.Cells(1, i).Value) = j
            Else
                objDict.Add wksDest.Cells(1, i).Value, j
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next i

'\\ Loop through mapped columns
For i = 0 To UBound(lngArr)
    '\\ For wksDest use column index by i + 1
    '\\ For wksSrce use stored value in array lngArr(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

You obviously will have to change the variables to suit your situation including header rows that you are matching.